# how to ignore validation of type of range input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, jquery-plugins

hello I have one input range slider in my form.

```
<input class="form-control" type="range"  min="0" max="100"  step="1" name="ageRange" id="ageRange" value="0"   >
```

I validate form with jquery.validate.min.js. though I have no any jquery validate rules for ageRange input
it is validated .  when moving slide bar and select then I got this message  **"Please enter a value less than or equal to 100"**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's validated because of the `max` & `min` attributes you've given here.
So, if you want to ignore the validation in this particular field, you can remove the min and max attributes.

Comment: yes when removing min and max it ignore validation.thanks.  but when min=0 and max=0 and input type="range" I select  40 value and I got error. 0<40<100  though 40 value is true I got error. why?

Comment: U're setting min = 0 & also max = 0. Instead you should set min = 0 but max = 100